# How to make a spiral lollipop?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, screw-modifier

So I'm attempting to recreate this specific lollipop for a class. I was able to model the lollipop, but I'm unable to recreate the twist with 4 colors. I tried modeling 4 elongated cubes and using a simple deform to twist them. I got the result I wanted but it wouldn't work if I tried making it follow the spiral path. I also did a screw modifier on a circle and didn't know how to make it follow the spiral path either.

How would you approach this in the most efficient way?

[image]

[image]

Edit: I made the lollipop! Thanks for the help!
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Screw Modifier with the Curve modifier is a good way to go.

Here is an image example
[image]

[image]

If you wanna put colors, use Circle Meshes instead (Shift + A > Mesh> Circle) with a fill tipe Ngon and add the colors to each circle

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it to work, this workflow was a lot efficient than the hand tweaking was doing with the simple deform. Would you know a method on how to assign color to each of those strands? I tried looking if I could apply the mirror and assign the material to the vertices. That didn't work. I was thinking of UV mapping after applying the modifiers? Although, the mesh would be rather dense and hard to UV map... again, thank you for the help!

Comment: If you wanna put color only, use Circle Meshes instead (Shift + A > Mesh> Circle) with a fill tipe Ngon and add the colors to each circle i updated the answer to add a second image