# Anyway to create this kind of rope animation in blender?

Tags: animation

Anyway to create this kind of animation in blender? I believe this one was originally created in C4D, But i wanted to see if its possible to create something like this in blender what would be the best way to go about it?

Im wanting to create similar rope animation but cant seem to find a way to create it. https://www.instagram.com/reel/ChAJ_33A-7p/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Also please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Screw modifier https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/196297/how-to-make-a-spiral-lollipop/196306#196306

Answer (score 1):

You could create one unique object with several cylinder meshes inside, assign the top vertices to a vertex group, parent to an empty:

[image]

Give it a *Cloth* physic, choose the vertex group as *Pin* group:

[image]

Rotate the empty. If the simulation goes too fast you can reduce the *Speed Multiplier* value:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate it!